# Contradiction between Taylor's theorem and properties of the Taylor series of $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

It seems to me that there is a contradiction between the Taylor's theorem and the properties of the Taylor series of the function $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ if $x\ne0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$.

On the one side, with the above extension $f$ is $C^\infty$ at $x=0$ and the Taylor series $TS[f]_0(x)$ of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ is identically null with a radius of convergence $R_c=\infty$, whereas $f(x)\ne 0$ for $x \ne 0$. As a consequence, $TS[f]_0(x)\ne f(x)$,  $\forall x\ne0$.

On the other side, Taylor's theorem states that an expansion at the order $n$ gives:
$f(x)=f(0)+\frac{f'(0)}{1!}x+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2+...+\frac{f^{(n)}}{n!}x^n+h_n(x)x^n, \qquad$ with $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}h_n(x)=0$

So this means that we should get better approximations of $f(x)$ when $n$ increases. Which is then not the case in this particular example as increasing $n$ doesn't make a difference in the polynomial expansion.

Now, what is the problem here? Is it that we cannot apply Taylor's theorem in this particular case, and if so, why? Or is it that it is wrong to express the rest as $h_n(x)x^n$ with $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}h_n(x)=0$?

Alternatively, what special properties could have the functions $h_n(x)$ that doesn't make $h_n(x)x^n$ become smaller when $n$ increases?

Or am I missing something else?

Comment: The taylor series only converges to the function if the remainder tends to $0$ in some neighborhood, not just at the point we are looking for. This is the case, for example, if the derivates are all bounded in a neighborhood. In this case, the taylor series converges to the function in this neighborhood.

Comment: $f(x)$ is a non-analytic smooth function, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Approximation_and_convergence

Comment: What you say about Taylor's theorem is true - there's no contradiction. Taylor's theorem does _not_ say that the remainder tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. Saying $\lim_{x\to0}h_n(x)=0$ says nothing about $\lim_{n\to\infty}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I assume the OP is referring to [the Peano remainder version of the theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_in_one_real_variable)?

Comment: @david-c-ullrich What would the theorem say about the remainder in this case?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes. _Since_ he said there was a contradiction, I assumed without reading closely that he was saying that the remainder tended to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. That would give a contradiction.

Comment: The theorem is in every calculus book. Also Wikipedia. The first thing you said, about $x\to0$, is one of the things the theorem says.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Fair enough -- but the OP never explicitly mentioned anything about $\lim_{n\to \infty}h_n(x)$, except the confusing sentence "So this means that we should get better approximations\cdot". Her/his statement of the theorem is correct.

Comment: @david-c-ullrich Actually, I _was_ reading the wikipedia pages and had trouble with this specific issue, that's why I came here to ask.

Comment: Fine. As has been said a few times already: What you say about $x\to0$ is correct. It simply does not follow from that that we get better approximations as $n\to\infty$. No contradiction.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You are right and the wikipedia page on [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) was a bit misleading, saying: "_Similarly, we get still better approximations to $f$ if we use polynomials of higher degree, since then we can match even more derivatives with $f$ at the selected base point._" Although it then tempers by saying: "_In **general** (it's me who highlights), the error in approximating a function by a polynomial of degree $k$ will go to zero a little bit faster than $(x − a)^k$ as $x$ tends to $a$._"

Comment: And a little later it says explicitly that this doesn't always happen. _Anyway_, you're really looking at the wrong version, from this point of view. The theorem you quote, that the page calls the most basic version is really not what most people think of as Taylor's Theorem. You should look at the results in the next section. "Explicit forms of the remainder". _Those_ are the theorems that do say the approximation gets better as $n$ increases, "in general"...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich This latter part, I have just added it for future readers of that page after the replies that have been made here. :) It is true that reading through the whole page and related ones one can understand that the remainder might not become better, yet, I had a hard time to conceive how this could be possible, thus my question. Thank you for the additional explanation about the different forms of the theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confused about what the theorem you cite says.

Take $h_n(x) = f(x) x^{-n}= \begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if} x=0 \\ \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x^n} &\text{ otherwise.} \end{cases}$

It does satisfy $\lim_{x\to 0} h_n(x) = 0$, and all the properties promised by the theorem. There is no contradiction.

---

*But it is utterly useless in order to approximate $f$ more and more finely by a sequence of polynomials forming the partial sums of a power series, "as $n$ grows." The whole point is exactly that: $f$ cannot be well approximated by such a family of polynomials around $0$. Trying to do so, no matter what degree $n$ you choose, you get a zero polynomial, and the remainder/error is... well, $f$.*

Comment: Thanks a lot. Expressing $h_n(x)$ using the expression of $f(x)$ makes it all clearer. I should have thought about it! Nice.

Comment: You're welcome! Also, this function is a nasty piece of work. (A useful one, but nasty.)

Answer (score 2):

*Taylor's theorem* is perfectly true, even in this case. Simply, the value of the function is entirely in its complementary term. This is one case where the *Taylor's series* does *not* converge to the value of the function.

$\mathcal C^\infty$ functions with a Taylor's series which converge to the value of a function are called *analytic* functions.

Thus you see *analytic functions* and $\mathcal C^\infty$ *functions are different notions, for functions of a real variable.

For functions of a *complex variable*, the situations is quite different: a function which is differentiable is *ipso facto* $\mathcal C^\infty$  and *analytic*.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that Taylor's theorem has a *weak indication* that the approximations *should* be improving.  In particular, we can rephrase the theorem as follows:

> Let $f_n$ denote the $n$th-order approximation of $f$.  Then the error $e_n(x) = f(x) - f_n(x)$ satisfies
>   $$
> \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e_n(x)}{x^n} = 0
> $$
>   which is to say that $e_n(x) \to 0$ faster than $x^n$ (i.e. $e(x) = o(x^n)$).

In a more "typical" Taylor approximation, this pattern would indicate an *improvement* of $e_n$ as $n \to \infty$, which is to say that $e_n$ approaches zero progressively more quickly and that $e_n(x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  We could see this with the Taylor series for $f(x) = e^x$, for example.

However, note that the theorem does not actually imply that this is the case.  For our problem, we will always have
$$
e_n(x) = f(x)
$$
and it just so happens that $f(x) \to 0$ faster than $x^n$ for any $n$.

Comment: ??? You say this would typically indicate that. I don't see how the true fact about $x\to0$ says anything at all about the approximation improving as $n\to\infty$. Given that it doesn't actually _imply_ any such thing, could you explain how it would typically "indicate" improvement as $n\to\infty$? (Other forms of the remaineder do typically indicate this - I really don't see at all how this version says anything in this direction, even heuistically)

Comment: @David First of all, when I say "typically", I mean "with the usual function one encounters in a calculus class" (as opposed to something about cardinalities or measures).  If we knew that at each step the error $e_n(x)$ is as bad as it can possibly be (something like $e_n(x) \sim Cx^{n+1}$), then this theorem does imply an improvement as $n \to \infty$.  Moreover, with a "typical sequence of functions", a steady decrease of error indicates that error will tend to zero.  Again, none of these "expected behaviors" are actually implied by the theorem.

Comment: @David while it is true that nothing truly surprising happened if you read the theorem closely enough and have zero other expectations, it's important to address why exactly the result is so counterintuitive (without an appeal to complex analysis).

Comment: Thanks, but nothing you said answers my question, as far as I can see. Yes, it's important to address why things are counterintuitve, when they are. Seems to me the reason the current situation is countereintuitive is just that we have an inutition based on experience that every function is analytic - I simply don't see what the result about $x\to0$ says about that.

Comment: @David The $x \to 0$ portion states that for any $n$, the error satisfies $e_n(x) = o(x^n)$.  This typically indicates that the error is getting smaller.  Yes, it could also indicate that $e_n(x) = e(x)$ where $e(x) \to 0$ more quickly than any polynomial function, but that's not the obvious possibility.

Comment: If you say so - I don't see how that typically indicates that the error is getting smaller. Of course the reason it doesn't prove any such thing is that it's really what one might call $o_n(x^n)$. But that aside, $|x|^n$ is not even a decreasing function of $n$, unless $|x|<1$. So in the "typical" case where this puurported intution is correct power series never have radius of convergence larger than $1$?

Comment: Again, I agree that _other forms of_ Taylor's theorem _do_ "indicate" that the series "typicaly" converges; they give explicit bounds on the remainder, which typically tend to $0$.

Comment: I've never seen that $o_n$ notation, that's interesting.  In any case, I'm talking about asymptotics as $x \to 0$ (as opposed to "as $x \to \infty$").  Indeed, as $x \to 0$, $|x|^n \to 0$, so yes: it makes sense to talk about approaching zero "more quickly than $x^n$".  And I would say that even in the typical case, this theorem makes no indication of what the series' radius of convergence should be.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly where my confusion came from. From my "typical" (i.e. "analytic") conception of the rate of convergence to 0, I could not conceive a sequence of functions $h_n(x)$ that satisfies (reconciliates) both requirements that $lim_{x\rightarrow0}h_n(x) = 0$ and that $h_n(x)x^n$ is independent of $n$. Very interesting to realize that when ranking the rates of convergence, there can be such a thing as converging faster than $x^n$ for any $n$, and yet converging more or less faster. Now, from the answer of Clement C. and your answer, I do see it. Transfinite exponents??...

Comment: @Quark I wouldn't bring transfinite numbers into this.  It suffices to say that there are functions that increase/decrease faster than any polynomial/rational function.  These functions are important to the [study of Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Very well, thank you for your reply and for the link!